# Excel. Sumif with special specific ifs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to understand how to do the following sumif;

- I have three pages
- Page 1 & 2 has same layout

Page 1 has column range A with specific numbers, and column range 2 with sums of other cells.

Page 2 has column range A with specific numbers, and column range 2 with sums of other cells.

Page 3 contains an empty table. I want to use it to sum the cells at column range 2 on page 1 and 2, IF the row contain a similar number on column range 1 on page 1 and 2.

Example:
I want excel to search column A on page 1 & 2, and outputs the cell on Column rage B at Page 3.
I also want it to sum the cells on column range B with the other cells on column range B on the other page IF a row that has the same special number.

Example result:

[image]

Comment: I havnt done this before, so I dont know where to start.

Comment: You need to do something before we can help you. You mention `sumif` in the question, start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing where to start when you are not familiar with Excel can be frustrating. Here is a simple way to do what you want by using the [`SUMIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) function (click this link and read how it works).

In your Sum total column cells on page 3 you can use this to get the totals from the other sheets and add them together.

Following the syntax of `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])` from the above link we will create two `SUMIF` statements and add them together;

- `range` = the range you want to check. In this case you want to check
  the column A numbers on each of the other sheets.
- `criteria` = what you want to check the range against. In this case,
  column A of page 3 is the criteria.
- `[sum range]` = this designates what numbers it will sum if it finds a
  match.

> =SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet3!A:A,Sheet1!B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet3!A:A,Sheet2!B:B)

This finds the matches of `Specific Numbers` from sheet 3 on the other sheets and then adds the `Sum of other cells` values that match.

Copy the formula into the cells you want totals in.

[image]

Comment: Great! You can use this function in many other situations, so make note of it. :-)

Comment: I will! This is a lifesaver! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer use multiple consolidated ranges for Pivot Table

Alt+D then P to open the Pivot table and chart wizard
select the multiple consolidation ranges and pivot table options

Add ranges

Page1!$A$2:$B$6

Page2!$A$13:$B$16

place results in your page 3